# On Relativity and Simultaneity

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

I’m no physicist. I have read a bit of special relativity and have been puzzled by a problem I thought of.

Suppose there’s a space ship oriented away from you and that it also is moving away from you at a rate of v m/s.
Say that Alice is sitting in the middle of that space ship and at each end of the space ship is a machine. Each machine holds one end of a metal pole that stretches across and is parallel to the floor of the spaceship.
Suppose that from Alice point of view, she’s set up a system where she switches on a light bulb that she’s holding and when the light reaches both machines they each raise up their end of the metal pole to the top of the space ship at the same speed. In her view, throughout the period that the pole is being raised it is seen as horizontal to the floor of the space ship.

However, from your point of view, the light signals do not reach both machines simultaneously so they do no begin raising the pole at the same time. Does this mean that you would see the pole being raised at an angle to the floor of the space ship? Or am I misinterpreting something?

Also, even though you do not agree that the machines start to raise the pole at the same time (nor finish doing so at the same time), would you agree that they both raise the pole at the same speed?

Comment: Presumably that space ship has to be quite long and travel very fast. As an external observer how would you measure the pole's elevation at different distances from Alice ? I think if you get to the bottom of that it will turn out to be one of the many false SR paradoxes. Light signals come to mind that would have to be reflected by the poles and be registered by "us" sitting on earth.

Comment: For an observer not on the spaceship, the two poles raise up at different time. This is essentially the "garage paradox". You can look it up. I don't understand what you mean by the pole being raised at an angle with the floor. If an observer imaging a line from the point of ship-pole contact to the edge of the pole when it's raising, them this line should be always normal to the ship floor.

Comment: @BohanXu I’m sorry, I don’t quite get your last sentence. I agree with you that the two poles rise at different times for an observer outside the space ship. But say you and I are holding two ends of a pole and you raise one end up while I’ve kept my end in place then the pole is raised at an angle to the floor(since you end is higher than mine, until I raise mine as well ). Doesn’t this mean that an actual observer outside who sees one end rise before the other will this see the pole inclined at an angle to the horizontal?

Comment: @KurtG. I expect the problem to be a false paradox as well (I also don’t see an angle of elevation as constituting a paradox). I’m just interested in knowing what an observer sees. I’m no physicist (nor mathematician) so I actually don’t know how to construct a mechanism for measuring the elevation  Let’s just say that the observer has an extremely good camera that can takes multiple snapshots at a fast  enough rate to capture most of the process. Would the images show an angle of elevation?

Comment: I do not quite agree with the belief that the pole is always parallel to the ship-floor. This is not even true for Alice. If she could notice the pole moving up in the same instant when the machine starts operating this would mean that a signal would have travelled from the machine to her instantly. This is impossible. I have read somewhere on this forum that SR prohibits rigid bodies for the same reason. A rigid pole could be used to push and transmit signals instantly.

Comment: @KurtG. Indeed that is true. Alice would actually need to recalculate after the fact to find that both ends of the pole were always at the same height. This would allow her to know that the pole was always parallel to the ship’s floor. She couldn’t observe it instantly as time would need to pass for the light to reach her (and she wouldn’t be able to see both ends at the same time as she’d have to turn her head). But via calculation I believe she’d find them to be horizontal.

Comment: Not only that the pole would be at an angle, but if you had a bunch of lifting machines along the whole length of the pole, they would too lift at different offsets, to form a slope, as seen from the rest frame. And if these machines had clocks on them, they would show a decreasing sequence of times. This is because you're looking at a differently *angled* time-slice compared to Alice; you see the two ends (and everything) as simultaneous, but what *you* observe as the trailing end *hasn't happened for her yet*, and the leading end that *you* see is already in her past, from her perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in a frame moving relative to the ship the pole would not be horizontal, since in that frame one end of the pole would have started rising earlier than the other. The same effect accounts for the length contraction of the pole- in the moving frame the positions of the trailing edge of the pole and the leading edge may be considered at two simultaneous instants, but in the pole's rest frame those two instant's are not simultaneous: the instant at which the trailing edge is considered in the moving frame is later, which means that the trailing edge has had an opportunity to move forward in the meantime, which results in the pole seeming shorter.

Comment: Thank you, could you answer the other question? Would the observer outside consider both machines to have raised the pole at the same speed? Even if not at the same time

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that the pole is always horizontal in the ship frame.  It **is** true that in the ship frame, the left and right ends of the pole are always at the same height, while in your frame they are not.  But in the ship frame, the center of the pole is not always at the same height as the ends, because it takes time for the center of the pole to "learn" that it's being pushed upward; until then, the pole is deformed into something like a V-shape.

Comment: Oh yes, that’s true. I didn’t even think of that. I suppose if instead she had multiple machines (that she’d programmed to be synchronized - each machine would wait until the photons finally reach the last machines before they start lifting) along the length of the pole then it would be closer to a straight line. Though that would still be only approximately because the information still has to travel from the point of contact of one machine to the halfway point between machines so it would look like multiple V shapes.